# How can I display data that is [int, str], [str, str] type from JSON to LWC DataTable

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, json, lightning-datatable

I'm trying to display data from HTTP API response from third system in LWC app.

The problem is, that some of that data that I get from the external system is in following types:

[image]

I have trouble display the selected columns. If the returned data is just str || int .. data is properly displayed.

The mapping loop is as following:

```
.then(response => {
                let responseData = JSON.parse(response);
                var data = [];
                responseData.data.forEach(row => {
                  let newRow = {};
                      row.forEach((element, index) => {
                    newRow[this.columns[index].fieldName] = element;
                  });
                  data.push(newRow);
                });
                this.data_Datatable = data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
JSON.stringify(newRow[this.columns[index].fieldName] = element);
```

Thank you.

**EDIT 1 11/17/2022** - Forgot to attach datatable screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, I have 2 columns completely empty - those are the types that are [str, int], or [int, int] ...

**EDIT 2 11/17/2022 - ADDED JSON response:**

```
    {
        "data": [
            [
                "1802523701456533",
                "701300b97e2e1000",
                "2021-03-08T03:09:57",
                [
                    1,
                    "Smartphone"
                ],
                "Galaxy S6"
            ],
            [
                "15250809629146723",
                "5957676d3b753f69",
                "2021-02-18T07:19:04",
                [
                    1,
                    "Smartphone"
                ],
                "Galaxy S6 Edge+"
            ],
            [
                "20487780899778413",
                "7a5911e7f5731400",
                "2021-01-26T15:54:48",
                [
                    0,
                    "Desktop"
                ],
                ""
            ],
            [
                "27450806533608027",
                "186af40e19b1cfdf",
                "2021-02-27T00:55:45",
                [
                    1,
                    "Smartphone"
                ],
                "iPhone"
            ],
            [
                "41195804276029081",
                "2ec0802a5c592800",
                "2021-01-22T06:33:13",
                [
                    0,
                    "Desktop"
                ],
                ""
            ], ...]
"meta": {
        "columns": [
            "session_id",
            "visitor_id",
            "timestamp",
            "device_type",
            "device_model"
        ],
        "count": 1356
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3 11/17/2022**

[image]

Defined outsite od LWC class:

```
import SystemModstamp from '@salesforce/schema/Account.SystemModstamp';

const flatten = (obj) => {
  return [...obj].map(item => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      return ('' + flatten(item)).split(',');
      }
    else {
      return '' + item
    }
  });
}

export default class mainComponent extends LightningElement {
```

LWC Apex imperative call -->

```
}).then(response => {
        let responseData = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log('responseData.data ===== \n' + responseData.data);
        this.data_Datatable = flatten(responseData.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        his.error = error;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some of the data? It looks like in addition to variable data types, there are variable numbers of elements?

Comment: I forgot to attach a screenshot of the data table. Thank you for that. Fixed - EDIT 1.

Comment: Without seeing the JSON/XML/whatever, you're asking us to guess what the data looks like. Also, the `columns` configuration would help demystify this issue.

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer if you just gave us maybe 5-6 lines of actual data (not a screenshot). I can't actually read the screenshot

Comment: @CasparHarmer added couple of JSON response data

Comment: @CasparHarmer I tried your first answer, it was still the same, the columns with [str, int] .., were empty.

Comment: Edited. This version works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm how about this recursive function:

```
const flatten = (obj) => {
  return [...obj].map(item => {
    if (Array.isArray(item) ){
      return ('' + flatten(item)).split(',');
    }
    else {
      return '' + item
    }
  });
}

let flattened = flatten(data);
```

It works on each row.
`flatten` takes the array (or object) and for each item in the array, it either appends a string (converting it to a string) or if it's still an array, it calls itself again.

To call this, define `flatten` outside the LWC class - as a const like above. Then invoke like this:

```
this.data_Datatable = flatten(responseData.data);
```

You'll be able to entirely skip the `forEach` loop that you have.

---

Check out a JSFiddle demonstrating this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ybn3jkq8/)

Comment: I don't see the data anymore, something's missing. Tried console.log the response from apex API call - I got the correct response as previously.

Comment: edited answer - see above.

Comment: Edit 3 added the .then and LWC outside definition of const flatten - data is still not shown :|

Comment: You'll have to open up the console and debug this. I took your dataset and ran it through the method above and it worked. I'll update the question with this.

Comment: Thank you for your time. :)